# IF statement w/ drop down?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use a drop down list with an if statement so when I choose a company from a drop down list some information will automatically fill in.

The company names are in column AF, the year is in column E, the claims info is in AB; SL Prem in AC; CF in AD; and Exp in AE. I need the claims, SL Prem, CF and EXP to automatically change when I select a company from the drop down list.

How can I write a formula so that when I select "company 1" it automatically sums all the claims information for 2013, 2014, etc.

A screenshot of how I have it organized:

[image: Inputs & Outputs]

Comment: Look into SUMIFS(), but that depends on how your data is set up.  You have shown us the output but not the input, so it is hard to give you anything more specific.

Comment: Hmmm I did an IF statement with a SUMIFS and it worked for the first  group, but when I tried to add a second IF statement so that when aa19="company 2" adds up all of their info it was giving me a #VALUE.

I'll attach a picture of the inputs as well :)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the formula you have tried. I don't understand your screenshot. Everything is zero or empty. What is the input? what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the Table like this?
[image]

[image]

If yes, please use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($AA$1=$AF$11:$AF$27)*($AA2=$E$11:$E$27)*AB$11:AB$27)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I would like to suggest a two step solution to fix the issue:**

[image]

**Step 1:**

- Enter this array (CSE) formula in Cell `I65`, finish with
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($F$65:$F$73, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($I$64:I64,$F$65:$F$73), 0)),"")}
  ```
- From **D**ata TAB click **V**alidation then from **A**llow, select
  **L**ist then assign range `I65:I67` to **S**ource.

**Step 2:**

- Write this array (CSE) formula in cell `B78`, finish with
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$65:$A$73, MATCH(0, IF($A$75=$F$65:$F$73, COUNTIF($H$77:$H77, $A$65:$A$73), ""), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Enter this formula in cell `C78` & fill across.

  ```
  =IF(SUMIFS(B$65:B$73,$F$65:$F$73, $A$75,$A$65:$A$73,$B78)=0,"",SUMIFS(B$65:B$73,$F$65:$F$73, $A$75,$A$65:$A$73,$B78))
  ```

**N.B.**

- Keep selecting Underwriter/Company name from **D**rop Down in cell `A75` to get claim
  details .
- For neatness later on you may hide range `I64:I67`.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*